# Switch statement using strstr always validates as true?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have the following switch statement.

The URL contains a referral ID e.g twitter, facebook or an email e.g mail@mail.com. This is stored as `$ref`

I have the following switch statement:

```
switch ($ref) {
    case "twitter":
        echo "twitter";
        break;
    case "facebook":
        echo "facbeook";
        break;
    case "blog":
        echo "blog";
        break;
    case strstr($ref,'@'):
        echo "email = ".$ref;
    default:
        echo "no referral found";
        break;
}
```

However if URL is passed with nothing (e.g just `www.mything.co.uk`) then I wish to go to the `default` case.

Instead, I get the following output:

```
email = no referral found
```

Why does the default also include the text I set for `case strstr($ref,'@')` ?

Comment: Do not do this: `case strstr($ref,'@'):` it is terrible practice

Comment: @BartHaalstra can you explain why it is terrible practice

Comment: This is not what a switch is created for. Switch is to match a variable to an static value. Almost all other languages do not even allow a dynamic value in the case. Just remove the case and do an if statement in the default case.

Comment: Also it makes the code a lot harder to understand as needed and is more error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP question: "**Why does the default also include the text I set for case strstr($ref,'@') ?**"

Answer: there's no `break;` following the output, and thus **falls through** to the default case.

**UPDATE:** Addressing the issue of putting a statement within a `case`, I'm also including an easy work-around:

```
switch ($ref) {
    case "twitter":
        echo "twitter";
        break;
    case "facebook":
        echo "facbeook";
        break;
    case "blog":
        echo "blog";
        break;
    default:
        if (strstr($ref,'@')) {
          echo "email = ".$ref;
        } else {
          echo "no referral found";
        }
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When `$ref` is an empty String, then `strstr($ref,'@');` returns an empty string too, this is why the `case strstr($ref,'@'):` matches the switch input `$ref.`
The problem is, you can't even use a email validation function like

```
 filter_var($ref, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

That would return `false` in case of an empty input instead of an empty string, but `switch` does loose comparison, meaning that an `"" == false` would return `true`:

http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose

Thus the only solution I see is to use an if statement using the `===` operator:

```
if($ref == 'twitter') {
        echo "twitter";
} else if($ref == 'facebook') {
        echo "facbeook";
} else if($ref == 'blog') {
        echo "blog";
} else if($ref === filter_var($ref, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "email = ".$ref;
} else {
        echo "no referral found";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because your test is performed like `if ($ref == strstr($ref, '@'))`, where `strstr` returns `false` which equals an empty string. You cannot really use dynamic comparisons in `switch` statements. Use `if..else` if you need that. Alternatively, abuse `switch` a bit:

```
switch (true) {
    case $ref == 'twitter':
       ..
    case strstr($ref, '@'):
       ..
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That will work:

```
case (strstr($ref, '@') ? true : false):
```

But it's not really good of practice.

Comment: 1) `strstr` already returns a *truthy* value or `false`, casting this explicitly to a boolean doesn't change much. 2) It'll still fail the same.